# multiple image maps not working in firefox

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox

I got stuck again between browsers compatability issues, what I was trying todo is to link different parts of image using image maps.

I am using two image maps for respective images.

using

two maps MAP1 and MAP2,

MAP1 works fine in all the browsers but MAP2 didnt worked in firefox,chrome,safari.

Both maps works fine in Internet Explorer.

Please enlighten me on this.
thnx in advance.

Comment: May be id of the image be the problem. Map Images using Dreamviewer. It may work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of image maps you can use div's by positioning them as absolute and adjusting the top and left co-ordinates and width and height. to start give border to the div and once you have placed them where you want, remove the border.
hope this is helpful, i am also using this technique :)